# Minor ticks in d3 V4 with out data for minor ticks using time range

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to add ticks to the x-axis using the time range data between 2 dates. I just have 2 dates and Major ticks are being drawn as expected. And d3 expects data to draw minor ticks in V4.

I am using d3 V4 and s3.subDivide() is depreciated in V4. Is there any method or way like subdivide where it draws minor ticks with out giving data?

My code:

```
let x = d3.scaleTime().rangeRound([0, width]);
let g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
x.domain([minDate, maxDate]);
g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "axis x_axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));
```

Visualization drawn by the above code is shown below.

[image]

I want result like below minor ticks with no data.

[image]

Comment: Can you provide an example of what the result you want should be? I can't understand your issue

Comment: @torresomar updated the question as requested

Answer (score 0):

An approach to get the desired result could be the following:

```
var xAxis = d3
  .axisBottom(x)
  .tickFormat((d, i) => (i % 2 ? multiFormat(d) : "")) // show the tick value in even index numbers for the axis
  .ticks(50); // set an optional number of ticks to display
```

The multiformat function is defined as follows:

```
var formatMillisecond = d3.timeFormat(".%L"),
  formatSecond = d3.timeFormat(":%S"),
  formatMinute = d3.timeFormat("%I:%M"),
  formatHour = d3.timeFormat("%I %p"),
  formatDay = d3.timeFormat("%a %d"),
  formatWeek = d3.timeFormat("%b %d"),
  formatMonth = d3.timeFormat("%B"),
  formatYear = d3.timeFormat("%Y");

function multiFormat(date) {
  return (d3.timeSecond(date) < date
    ? formatMillisecond
    : d3.timeMinute(date) < date
    ? formatSecond
    : d3.timeHour(date) < date
    ? formatMinute
    : d3.timeDay(date) < date
    ? formatHour
    : d3.timeMonth(date) < date
    ? d3.timeWeek(date) < date
      ? formatDay
      : formatWeek
    : d3.timeYear(date) < date
    ? formatMonth
    : formatYear)(date);
}
```

[Working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/RIhvpTwPIs8C6BOeW2Di?p=preview)